# How do I cut grooves in self-leveling concrete to incorporate an existing drain?

Tags: basement, floor, drainage, level, self-leveling-concrete

This is a follow up question to my previous question about [leveling a basement floor without losing the drainage](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/9292/how-do-i-level-a-basement-floor-but-not-the-slab-underneath).  After the feedback I decided to use self-leveling concrete and cut (or form it in advance) grooves (canals?) that lead to the existing drain.

I just found that I received an [answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/9292/how-do-i-level-a-basement-floor-but-not-the-slab-underneath/9397#9397) with the same idea.  But I'd like to elaborate more.  For example:

Is it necessary to redo the drain or can I just leave it lower, perhaps by just adding another grill on top?

Can I use forms, for example pieces of wood that go all directions (like rays) from the drain?

Or is the best idea to use a screw driver like Justin Kuhs suggests in his answer to me?  (BTW, Justin, thanks a lot for your answer, I didn't think of the screw driver at all, great idea!)

Have people here done such things?  What were your experiences?

Comment: How big is the area you'll be leveling, and how much height do you intend to add to the floor?

Comment: Good question.  I'm not at home at the moment, but I think roughly the area would probably be less than 24 ft2 and it would probably be 2" at its deepest max.

Comment: Is self-leveling concrete rated for 2" thickness? Find out before you start the pour.

Comment: Good hint!  Haven't been to HD yet, but will find out.

Answer (score 4):

24 sq ft would be an area approximately 4x6?  Adding two inches of depth... I think what I would try in this case would be to get several 1/2" dowel rods and cut them to lengths that would allow me to align them in a radial pattern out from the drain, something like this:

[image]

Around the drain, I would prop them 1.5" up in the air, and at the periphery I'd prop them 2" up in the air, that way when I poured, I'd end up with 1/2" deep semi-circular troughs that ran downhill towards the drain.  Pour concrete, let it set up and remove the dowels.

DEFINITELY add a new drain cap on top of the old one as a 3" diameter 2" deep hole in the floor is a serious trip hazard.

Comment: You could use pvc pipe instead of dowels. It might be cheaper and easier to remove the pipe from the cement.

Comment: I would be concerned that concrete would get into the hollow pipe since it's self leveling concrete in question.  Removing the dowels after a few hours would be no more difficult than removing any other concrete forms.

Comment: Doesn't have to be drowels, right?  It can be 1x4 or whatever with the 1' at the bottom.  I'm thinking of just laying them on the floor since it has the slope already.

Comment: Sure - those would work - I was thinking dowels simply for the more rounded drain trenches