# Leveling basement floor while keeping it sloping to the drain?

Tags: basement, floor, drain, level, self-leveling-concrete

I am having similar problem with the basement slope being exceptionally steep around the floor drain (similar to this: [How do I level a basement floor but not the slab underneath?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/9292)). The discussion there seems to lead to a specific solution:

1. Extend the drain to the new level
2. Pour self-leveling cement to raise the floor
3. Create channels in the freshly poured cement for the water to drain

So the questions are:

- Is that a practical solution to this problem?
- If so, which method would be most effective in crating these water channels?

  - Using a wide screwdriver (how do you maintain consistent slope without displacing surrounding concrete)?
  - Laying down a pattern of 1/2" dowls/PVC pipes (how do you construct this pattern? what pattern would work best?)
  - What about cutting them in with a circular saw after the concrete sets (seems messy, time consuming, producing narrow channels with no slope?)

Well, as they say, a picture is worth a thousand words. So, ideally, I would like to see this method in action or in its finished state.

PS:
I am also considering laying down Delta FL over the entire area to act as a vapor barrier/subfloor; laminate on top...

Comment: If you are looking to put another floor over the top, I'd leave the drain and slope alone. Tooling channels into wet cement is one of those ideas that sounds better when you haven't tried it. There are fewer practical problems with saw cutting, especially if you do it soon, while the fresh cement is set, but not very strong yet. Slope is provided by shimming a board for the saw to ride on which develops the proper slope in the channels. Wider channels can be made by cutting parallel lines and breaking out the remains between them, though narrow saw cuts are perfectly adequate if kept clear.